# Looking for good small DES implementation

Tags: c, cryptography, embedded, des

I'm looking for a good permissive-licensed (BSD/MIT or PD) DES implementation in C, with minimal runtime memory usage (i.e. minimal amount of read-write memory, and preferably small code/table size too). Speed is not an issue; in fact, in some ways slower is better because it provides some natural defense against brute-force login attempts.

All of the traditional implementations I've seen do lazy/runtime initialization of huge tables, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I'd be happy to have the tables in `static const` data in the binary, and in fact this is what I've partly hacked onto an implementation I've got right now, but I'm wondering if there are any existing implementations that do a better job of minimizing the size of tables at the expense of performance so that the binary isn't so big (~50kb of tables).

Note: Yes, DES sucks. The intended usage case is for implementing the `crypt` function for handling traditional password logins.

Comment: Is there any reason you actually want to use DES nowadays, and not more modern algorithms? And what do you want to do, really encrypting anything, or implementing a hash function or similar based on DES (as your mention of "brute force login" indicates)?

Comment: Presumably this is for implementing the POSIX `crypt(3)` function? If so you should probably add this context to the question.

Comment: The reason why the lookup tables are used is for speed.  Did you want to optimize for small memory footprint or something?  EDIT: Actually, yes, you mentioned that, I fail at reading.

Comment: My understanding is that the sbox tables are necessary and difficult or impossible to optimize out, but that the permutation tables are just optimizations for speed. Maybe I should just RTFS better, figure out exactly what they're used for, and replace the table lookups with code to do whatever they're doing.

Comment: Why don't you just take `crypt` from BSD itself?

Comment: The code I'm using now is derived indirectly from BSD `crypt`, but it has the issues I described in the question (~50k of read-write tables, most of which seem unnecessary).

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sold on your DES need ... traditional `crypt` with DES is easily broken with brute-force by everyone which can get your stored (hashed) passwords. Do you really need to allow login with preexisting stored password tables? If not, better use modern algorithms like bcrypt or PBKDF-2 with a suitable work factor. (Scrypt is even more resistant to brute-force, but might not suit your "low memory" requirement.)

Comment: I agree other algorithms are "better", but they're useless here in the sense of not meeting compatibility needs. Hashes are not accessible and thus the only weakness of DES `crypt` is the fact that only 8 bytes of the password are significant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example with [MIT license](https://github.com/keplerproject/md5/blob/master/src/des56.c) and the version from [libtomcrypt](https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt/blob/master/src/ciphers/des.c) is completely free for all purposes.

The first version seems to do lazy initialization of the tables, too, whereas they are static consts in libtomcrypt. But libtomcrypt seems to give you a compilation flag for speed vs. size, there's a `#ifndef LTC_SMALL_CODE` in front of the larger tables, maybe that can solve your problem?

Comment: Tomcrypt might have the solution I'm looking for... checking.

Comment: Yep, looks great. Now I just need to figure out how to adapt it for DES with salt versus plain DES.

Comment: By the way, several of the remaining tables in tomcrypt are also wasteful. (A lookup table for `0x800000>>i` ?!)

Comment: Great! Yeah, sometimes there are some things in the code that could be optimized, but I guess it's still awesome that he created all this stuff with basically no restrictions regarding licensing...

Comment: Yes, indeed. I've always loved tomcrypt in principle, and now I'm glad to see the code is overall very nice.

Answer (score 0):

The [source code section from Applied Cryptography](http://www.schneier.com/book-applied-source.html) has links to a large number of DES implementations - I haven't looked at them all but there's a good chance that at least one of them meets your needs.